# Ffmpeg : Overlay 2 images on a video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I currently use OBS to do this and I got to wait til the video has been recorded which can take 20 - 40 min depending on the video length ... It's so long..

What I'm trying to do is this:

Background (under the video) and Overlay (on top of the video) : Opacity 20 (Img 1 and Img 2).

Video (in the middle) : Opacity 50 and Saturation -1 (Black and White).

Is it doable with ffmpeg and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the scale2ref, setsar, format, colorchannelmixer, hue, and overlay [filters](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html):

```
ffmpeg -i background.png -i video.mp4 -i foreground.png -filter_complex \
"[0][1]scale2ref[img1a][vid];[img1a]setsar=1[img1b]; \
 [vid]format=yuva444p,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5,hue=s=0[video]; \
 [2][img1b]scale2ref[img2a][img1]; \
 [img2a]format=yuva444p,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.2[img2]; \
 [img1][video]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2[bg];[bg][img2]overlay,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 1:a -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you, mmh, actually there is only img 1 and img 2 with the video "in the middle" like a sandwich, there isn't really a background. I'll try to adapt it though and come back to tell you if I suceeded (not very good with ffmpeg to be honest..). And also I removed the other thread as I got a reply in here.

Comment: Still got 2 issues : The first is that one of the images is set as the "overlay" in your formula and has no opacity set (which should be 0.2) so it appears too visible still :/ ; The second issue I took care of it, the images were too little compared to the video and ffmpeg cropped the video to the image size ... I resized them to the video size and it works fine now.. Can you help me with the opacity of the "overlay" please ? It's my last issue :( thanks !! @llogan

Comment: @SamoussaBinouMymusicisinme Answer updated.

Comment: The one you're refering at "Background.png" still has no opacity set :/ but nevermind, this answer is fine by me, I'll just try to find a solution, maybe reduce the brightness directly on the image or something, thanks anyway, you've been a great help ! Won't need to record the whole thing on OBS now, a good thing less to do ! :p @llogan